# Expand field of type object into separate fields in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to clean the data present in CSV format using pandas.

My data frame looks like the following:
[image]

I want to expand the shot_paramters field into individual columns.

Following is the sample value of the field:

[image]

Any ideas on how to achieve this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create list of DataFrames by `ast.literal_eval`, pass to `DataFrame` constructor and append to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'played_at_time':['2019-06-20', '2019-06-21'],
                   'shot_paramters':['{"ampact_angle":0,"swing_category":1}',
                                     '{"impact_offset":76}'],
                    'shot_name':['VSHOT','VSHOT']})
print (df)
  played_at_time                         shot_paramters shot_name
0     2019-06-20  {"ampact_angle":0,"swing_category":1}     VSHOT
1     2019-06-21                   {"impact_offset":76}     VSHOT

import ast

df1 = pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in df.pop('shot_paramters')], index=df.index)
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
  played_at_time shot_name  ampact_angle  swing_category  impact_offset
0     2019-06-20     VSHOT           0.0             1.0            NaN
1     2019-06-21     VSHOT           NaN             NaN           76.0
```

EDIT:

Another solution if all values are splitted by `,` and then possible split by `:`:

```
L = [dict([y.split(':') for y in x.split(',')])
                        for x in df.pop('shot_paramters').str.strip('{}')]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index).rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('"'))
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
  played_at_time shot_name ampact_angle swing_category impact_offset
0     2019-06-20     VSHOT            0              1           NaN
1     2019-06-21     VSHOT          NaN            NaN            76
```

EDIT1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'played_at_time':['2019-06-20', '2019-06-21'],
                   'shot_paramters':['{"ampact_angle":0:9,"swing_category":1}',
                                     '{"impact_offset"}'],
                    'shot_name':['VSHOT','VSHOT']})
print (df)
  played_at_time                           shot_paramters shot_name
0     2019-06-20  {"ampact_angle":0:9,"swing_category":1}     VSHOT
1     2019-06-21                        {"impact_offset"}     VSHOT

L = [dict([y.split(':', 1) if ':' in y else [y, None] for y in x.split(',')])
                        for x in df.pop('shot_paramters').str.strip('{}')]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index).rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('"'))
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
  played_at_time shot_name ampact_angle swing_category  impact_offset
0     2019-06-20     VSHOT          0:9              1            NaN
1     2019-06-21     VSHOT          NaN            NaN            NaN
```

Comment: I am getting ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x12e59e610>

Comment: If change `df1 = pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in df.pop('shot_paramters')], index=df.index)` to `df1 = pd.DataFrame([x for x in df.pop('shot_paramters')], index=df.index)` it working?

Comment: @VikasRoy - Unfortunately it means data are broken :(

Comment: is there a way to ignore some fields and set them as null?

Comment: I am getting: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 3; 2 is required

Comment: @VikasRoy - Can you change `y.split(':')` to `y.split(':', 1)` ?

Comment: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #23 has length 1; 2 is required